# Drupal theme() function and custom template

Tags: drupal

I have a custom module that returns data from a web service call. It comes back from an XML response, which I am converting to an array.

Once I have the array, I do:

```
$output = theme('search_srs_results', $data);
return $output;
```

But I am getting a white screen. No apache/php/watchdog errors.

I've done this before in another module without any difficulty. My theme hook is defined, and points to a template file, passing the $data argument. If I dump $output before it's returned, its NULL.

$data definitely has a populated array before being themed.

If I do theme('item_list', $data);, it renders, no white screen.

I tried reading the docs again on hook_theme and theme() but I don't seem to be doing anything wrong.

Here are the theme functions:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme()
 */

function srs_finder_theme() {
  return array(
    'search_srs_results' => array(
      'template' => 'srs-finder-results',
      'arguments' => array('data' => null),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_preprocess()
 */

function srs_finder_preprocess_search_srs_results(&$vars) {
  $data = $vars['data'];
}
```

Whats missing?

Comment: Did you clear cache in Perfomance page?

Comment: Yes, while I am developing this, I have cache_clear_all() in the _init(). Is that not enough?

Comment: where's theme_search_srs_results ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you need `hook_preprocess()` function at all. `$data` should automatically be available to `srs-finder-results.tpl.php`. Thats because you're passing this variable in the call `theme('src_src_results', $data)` and the fact that you have declared that there is 1 argument in `hook_theme()`.

`srs-finder-results.tpl.php` file should reside in the `src_finder` module folder. You need to implement the code for that! (Alternatively as nikit has commented above, provide a `theme_search_srs_results` function. In that case you will need to remove the `template` array entry)

[Note: If other users of the module want to override this theme template they can always provide their own implementation of `srs-finder-results.tpl.php` in the theme folder of the theme that is active.]

Comment: Already did all that. I guess it was Drupal caching issue, it started working after making sure it was off and clearing it a few times.